# Do I need to reinstall a Windows Service if I made changes in the code?

Tags: windows, service, windows-services

I wrote a windows service and installed it. Now I made a few changes to the code and rebuilded the solution.
Should I also reinstall the service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, just stop it, replace the files, and restart it.

Comment: Thanks! Which files should I replace?

Comment: Pretty much anything that makes up the service, the exe and any referenced dlls.